# Sending calls to voice mail

Tags: android, callblocking

I want to send the incoming call present in my blocked call list to voice mail.

1.) Is the only way to do it is by "SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL" present in ContactsContract api in android?

2.)If yes, then can i edit the contacts already present in my contacts list of phone so to add this flag to them?

Please share solution with some code or example or any useful link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi did u got solution. kindly share here please.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to listen for `incoming call` and then `disconnect it programmatially`...

To send to voice mail, voice mail facility should be activated on the device and after disconnecting it will automatically direct to voice mail if the calling person wants to send to voice mail.